# Python decodes byte string correctly on windows but not working on linux.Giving Unicode error

Tags: python, utf-8, python-unicode

I am trying to decode byte string which has unicode character EN DASH, to get the proper unicode string.

Below code is running fine on windows with python 3.6:

```
decode_header_sequence = [(b'Excel to csv \xe2\x80\x93 Conversion .csv', 'utf-8')]
print(decode_header_sequence[0][0].decode('utf-8'))
```

which gives me string - 'Excel to csv – Conversion .csv'

But when I execute the same lines on linux platform. Code is failing with unicode error:
'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 16-18: ordinal not in range(128)

I have tried almost everything that I found under the threads like this.But no luck.
Anyone can help me with solving this issue as i really don't know Why this is happening?

Comment: The decoding goes fine. The problems happen when you try to *print*.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica
what problem is happening there..can you please elaborate me this?

Comment: Possibly useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/57224678/5320906, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54599110/5320906.

Answer (score 0):

On windows I found sys.getfilesystemencoding() was set to UTF-8 and on linux it was set to ascii.Therefore on windows it was easily decoding utf-8 characters in the input string.But giving error on linux.I just get the rid of this by ignoring utf-8 characters from input string.
I decoded string as below :

```
ascii_String = input_string.decode('ascii', errors="ignore").encode('ascii')
```