# Request library python not behaving same in ec2 server and local jupyter notebook

Tags: python, python-requests, jupyter-notebook, ascii

Hi I am using python requests library to read contents of url.
On local jupyter notebook
following is python code:

```
import json
import requests
response = (requests.get("https://ws.bbc34.cs.streamuk.com/services/channelFeed.php?channel=zee5-punjabi&group=punjabi&output=rss2.0").text)
print((response))
```

and the response is something like:

> xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
> xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/"
> xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
> xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/">
>
> Zee5 Punjabi
> Zee5 Punjabi video rss feed
> https://ws.bbc34.cs.streamuk.com/
> <atom:link href="https://ws.bbc34.cs.streamuk.com/services/channelFeed.php"
> rel="self" type="application/rss+xml"/>
> Fri, 25 Sep 2020 08:01:54 GMT
> StreamUK Crowdsourcer (http://www.streamuk.com)
>
> https://ws.bbc34.cs.streamuk.com/images/feed-logo.png
> Zee5 Punjabi
> https://ws.bbc34.cs.streamuk.com/
>
> Fri, 25 Sep 2020 03:23:34 GMT
> openSearch:startIndex1</openSearch:startIndex>
> openSearch:itemsPerPage167</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
> openSearch:totalResults167</openSearch:totalResults>
>
> ਖੇਤੀ ਬਿਲਾਂ ’ਤੇ ਕਿਸਾਨ ਮੋਰਚਿਆਂ ’ਚੋਂ ਪੰਜਾਬ ਦੀਆਂ ਸਿਆਸੀ ਧਿਰਾਂ ਕੀ ਲੱਭ ਰਹੀਆਂ ਹਨ
> https://ws.bbc34.cs.streamuk.com/
> ਪੰਜਾਬ ਦੀਆਂ ਸਿਆਸੀ ਧਿਰਾਂ ਕਿਸਾਨਾਂ ਦੇ ਸਕੇ ਹੋਣ ਦੇ ਦਾਅਵੇ ਤਾਂ ਕਰ ਰਹੀਆਂ ਹਨ ਪਰ ਇਸ ਸੰਘਰਸ਼ ਵਿੱਚ ਉਨ੍ਹਾਂ ਦੇ ਨਿੱਜੀ ਮੁਫ਼ਾਦ ਕੀ
> ਹਨ
> ਨਿੱਜੀ,ਸਿਆਸੀ,ਸਿਆਸੀ ਧਿਰਾਂ,ਸੰਘਰਸ਼,ਧਿਰਾਂ,ਮੋਰਚਿਆਂ,ਮੁਫ਼ਾਦ,ਉਨ੍ਹਾਂ,ਕਿਸਾਨ,ਕਿਸਾਨਾਂ,ਰਹੀਆਂ,ਬਿਲਾਂ,ਦਾਅਵੇ,ਦੀਆਂ
> ਸਿਆਸੀ,ਦੀਆਂ ਸਿਆਸੀ ਧਿਰਾਂ,ਪੰਜਾਬ,ਪੰਜਾਬ ਦੀਆਂ,ਪੰਜਾਬ ਦੀਆਂ ਸਿਆਸੀ
> Fri, 25 Sep 2020 01:00:03 GMT
> https://ws.bbc34.cs.streamuk.com/:7e3ac643-fede-11ea-9778-000c29b9294a
> <media:content url="https://ws.bbc34.cs.streamuk.com/content/channels/zee5-punjabi/streams/p08sgysb294a7e3ac64387.mp4"
> fileSize="204902218" bitrate="4690" type="video/mp4" medium="video"
> duration="362" width="1920" height="1080"/>
> <media:thumbnail url="https://ws.bbc34.cs.streamuk.com/content/channels/zee5-punjabi/thumbnails/p08sgysb294a7e3ac643.jpg"
> width="170" height="128"/>
> media:keywordsਨਿੱਜੀ,ਸਿਆਸੀ,ਸਿਆਸੀ ਧਿਰਾਂ,ਸੰਘਰਸ਼,ਧਿਰਾਂ,ਮੋਰਚਿਆਂ,ਮੁਫ਼ਾਦ,ਉਨ੍ਹਾਂ,ਕਿਸਾਨ,ਕਿਸਾਨਾਂ,ਰਹੀਆਂ,ਬਿਲਾਂ,ਦਾਅਵੇ,ਦੀਆਂ
> ਸਿਆਸੀ,ਦੀਆਂ ਸਿਆਸੀ ਧਿਰਾਂ,ਪੰਜਾਬ,ਪੰਜਾਬ ਦੀਆਂ,ਪੰਜਾਬ ਦੀਆਂ
> ਸਿਆਸੀ</media:keywords>
>
>
> ਖੇਤੀ ਬਿੱਲ: ‘ਆਹ ਸਾਡੀ ਹੋਂਦ ਨੂੰ ਖ਼ਤਮ ਕਰਨ ਦਾ ਇੱਕ ਜ਼ਰੀਆ ਹੈ’
> https://ws.bbc34.cs.streamuk.com/
> ਕਿਸਾਨ ਧਰਨਿਆਂ ਵਿਚ ਪੁਰਸ਼ਾਂ ਦੇ ਨਾਲ ਇਸ ਵਾਰ ਮਹਿਲਾਵਾਂ ਵੀ ਵੱਡੀ ਗਿਣਤੀ ਪਹੁੰਚ ਕੇ ਆਪਣੀ ਹਾਜ਼ਰੀ ਭਰ ਰਹੀਆਂ ਹਨ
> ਗਿਣਤੀ,ਧਰਨਿਆਂ,ਮਹਿਲਾਵਾਂ,ਕਿਸਾਨ,ਰਹੀਆਂ,ਹਾਜ਼ਰੀ,ਪਹੁੰਚ,ਪੁਰਸ਼ਾਂ,ਜ਼ਰੀਆ
> Thu, 24 Sep 2020 15:47:35 GMT
> https://ws.bbc34.cs.streamuk.com/:b4417aea-fecb-11ea-9778-000c29b9294a
> <media:content url="https://ws.bbc34.cs.streamuk.com/content/channels/zee5-punjabi/streams/p08sfy25294ab4417aea87.mp4"
> fileSize="177778979" bitrate="4690" type="video/mp4" medium="video"
> duration="306" width="1920" height="1080"/>
> <media:thumbnail url="https://ws.bbc34.cs.streamuk.com/content/channels/zee5-punjabi/thumbnails/p08sfy25294ab4417aea.jpg"
> width="170" height="128"/>
> media:keywordsਗਿਣਤੀ,ਧਰਨਿਆਂ,ਮਹਿਲਾਵਾਂ,ਕਿਸਾਨ,ਰਹੀਆਂ,ਹਾਜ਼ਰੀ,ਪਹੁੰਚ,ਪੁਰਸ਼ਾਂ,ਜ਼ਰੀਆ</media:keywords>
>
>
> ਪੀਐੱਮ ਮੋਦੀ ਦੀ ਕਿਹੜੀ ਗੱਲ 'ਤੇ ਵਿਰਾਟ ਕੋਹਲੀ ਆਪਣਾ ਹਾਸਾ ਨਹੀਂ ਰੋਕ ਸਕੇ

This is as expected:

But the same piece of code I am trying to run on EC2 server with same requests library installed and same python version,But i am not able to print response.I am getting the following error.

print((response))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1168-1171: ordinal not in range(128)

I did check both the versions of python and requests library and were same.
python version:3.6
requests version:2.23

I am not able to find why this error.
Is it beacause of "ਗਿਣਤੀ,ਧਰਨਿਆਂ,ਮਹਿਲਾਵਾਂ,ਕਿਸਾਨ,ਰਹੀਆਂ,ਹਾਜ਼ਰੀ,ਪਹੁੰਚ,ਪੁਰਸ਼ਾਂ,ਜ਼ਰੀਆ" characters,but it worked fine in local jupyter.I am not getting it .Please help.

Comment: i ran locale on both my local and ec2 server,the results are:

Comment: [ec2-user@ip-172-31-37-106 news_xml_code]$ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-37-106 news_xml_code]$ result of ec2 server

Comment: 124s-MacBook-Air:~ a124$ locale
LANG=""
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_ALL=
124s-MacBook-Air:~ a124$ this is local machine

Comment: What is the output of `locale charmap` on the server?

Comment: [ec2-user@ip-172-31-37-106 news_xml_code]$ locale charmap
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
ANSI_X3.4-1968

Comment: The problem is that charmap value, which is basically ASCII.  You could try running your script with the PYTHONIOENCODING environment variable set, as described in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/57224678/5320906

Comment: Thanks a lot that worked but i cannot set the environment while running as it will be autmated in future ,can this be done via adding something in python code or can i set the server environment permanently.

Comment: You could perhaps set it in the server user's `.bashrc` or `.profile` file.