# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2103' in position 89

Tags: python, string, utf-8

Following code executes fine on my WIN10, Pycharm Laptop with Python 3.6:

```
import struct
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import UTC
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str

data = b'A\x10Vu\x87%\x00x\r\r\x03\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00$\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'

devid,hw,sw,bat,ss,mod,t1,dii,adc,t2,h,ts = struct.unpack('>6sBBHBBhBHhHL',data)

# fields that needed processing are done in the f-strings below
print(f"DeviceID={devid.hex()} HW={hw} SW={'.'.join(str(sw))}\n"
      f"BAT={bat:.3f}mV SignalStrength={-113+2*ss}dBm Mode={mod} Temp={t1/10}\N{DEGREE CELSIUS}\n"
      f"Door={dii==0x80} ADC={adc}mv Temp2={t1/10:.1f}\N{DEGREE CELSIUS} Humidity={h/10:.1f}%\n"
      f"Timestamp={datetime.fromtimestamp(ts,UTC)}")
```

However, when I execute the same code on my virtual ubuntu machine, I get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "decoderexample.py", line
> 11, in 
> print(f"DeviceID={devid.hex()} HW={hw} SW={'.'.join(str(sw))}\n" UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2103' in
> position 89

The Machine runs following python version:

> Python 3.6.5
>
> Distributor ID: Ubuntu Description:    Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Release:
> 18.04 Codename:       bionic

I have tried to use smart_str instead of str and I've also deleted the str statements from the print statement.

Comment: Hmm. Works for me on MacOS and a RHEL Linux VM.

Comment: works for me on Ubuntu 18.04 with Python 3.9.5 and Python 3.6.9. Note that the error comes from the character `℃`

Comment: Hmm. Works for me on Windows10, WSL _Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS_, Python 3.8.6 and `os.getenv("PYTHONIOENCODING")` returning `'utf-8'`…

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57224678/5320906, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54599110/5320906

Comment: As commented by @snakecharmerb following solution helped:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/57224678/16399680

Comment: Did you identify the underlying problem? What was it?